# I am attempting to do an array on my down time, but I need to try and link the 2 lists together to print them out

Tags: java, arrays, columnsorting

So I have had to leave my college course to help with the coronavirus and I am attempting to do an array on my down time, but I need to try and link the 2 lists together to print them out, can anyone help.

I am trying to get this done, I understand the theory of how it works but I just need pointed in the right directions

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    String []  fastestTimes = new String [10];
    double [] athletes = new double [10];

    fastestTimes [0] = "Richard Thompson";
    fastestTimes [1] = "Nesta Carter";
    fastestTimes [2] = "Usain Bolt";
    fastestTimes [3] = "Asafa Powel";
    fastestTimes [4] = "Tyson Ga";
    fastestTimes [5] = "Maurice Greene";
    fastestTimes [6] = "Justin Gatlin";
    fastestTimes [7] = "Christian Coleman";
    fastestTimes [8] = "Yohan Blake";
    fastestTimes [9] = "Steve Mullings";



    athletes [0] = 9.82;
    athletes [1] = 9.78;
    athletes [2] = 9.92;
    athletes [3] = 9.72;
    athletes [4] = 9.69;
    athletes [5] = 9.79;
    athletes [6] = 9.74;
    athletes [7] = 9.76;
    athletes [8] = 9.69;
    athletes [9] = 9.80;




    System.out.println("Array Before Bubble Sort");  

    for(double i=0; i < fastestTimes.length; i++){
        System.out.print(fastestTimes[(int) i] + " ");      
    }  
    System.out.println();  

    bubbleSort(fastestTimes);//sorting array elements using bubble sort  

    System.out.println("Array After Bubble Sort");  
    for(int i=0; i < fastestTimes.length; i++){  
        System.out.print(fastestTimes[(int) i] + " ");  
    }  

}
```

}

Comment: Define "link". Also, the first `i` should not be an `double` and you don't need the casts

Comment: Don't use parallel arrays. Java is an **Object-Oriented language**. Use it. Create a class with 2 fields, the create a single array of objects of that class.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by "link" you mean showing the speed for each athlete, try this:

```java
for(int i=0; i < fastestTimes.length; i++){
    System.out.print(athletes[i] + ": " + fastestTimes[i] + " seconds");      
}
```

In a `for` loop to go through an array, you want the index. The index (`i`) is an `int`. If you make it a `double` then you are forced to cast for nothing like you were doing.

Assuming my understanding of what you mean by "linking" two lists together is correct, you might also want to take a look at `java.util.Map`. It is like a dictionary where something (the key) maps to something else (the value). In a real dictionary, a word maps to its definition. If you know the word, you can find the definition.

In your case, you might want to consider mapping the athlete's name to his time and not have to carry around 2 lists.

Just a thought for further reading whenever you have down time again :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing it using disconnected data sets, which is a complex and error-prone way of doing it, you should do it using the OOP (Object Oriented Programming) concept. Given below is a sample which you can extend/customize further as per your requirement:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Athlete {
    private String name;
    private double fastestTime;

    public Athlete(String name, double fastestTime) {
        this.name = name;
        this.fastestTime = fastestTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getFastestTime() {
        return fastestTime;
    }

    public void setFastestTime(double fastestTime) {
        this.fastestTime = fastestTime;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Athlete [name=" + name + ", fastestTime=" + fastestTime + "]";
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Athlete[] athletes = new Athlete[3];
        athletes[0] = new Athlete("Richard Thompson", 9.82);
        athletes[1] = new Athlete("Nesta Carter", 9.78);
        athletes[2] = new Athlete("Usain Bolt", 9.92);

        System.out.println("Before sorting:");
        for (Athlete athlete : athletes) {
            System.out.println(athlete);
        }

        // Sort the array by fastestTime
        Arrays.sort(athletes, Comparator.comparing(Athlete::getFastestTime));

        System.out.println("Before sorting:");
        for (Athlete athlete : athletes) {
            System.out.println(athlete);
        }    
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Before sorting:
Athlete [name=Richard Thompson, fastestTime=9.82]
Athlete [name=Nesta Carter, fastestTime=9.78]
Athlete [name=Usain Bolt, fastestTime=9.92]
Before sorting:
Athlete [name=Nesta Carter, fastestTime=9.78]
Athlete [name=Richard Thompson, fastestTime=9.82]
Athlete [name=Usain Bolt, fastestTime=9.92]
```